# How to remove unwanted characters from JSON request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript.
I am facing this issue where I get  `[{"_id":1}]` as my results.
Does anyone know how can I get `1` as my output?

This is my code, I am calling it from a database.

```
function getaccountid() {
    var accID = new XMLHttpRequest();
    accID.open('GET', "http://127.0.0.1:8080/account" + "/" + sessionStorage.getItem("username"), true);
    accID.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    accID.send(JSON.parse);
    accID.onload = function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem("accountId", accID.response)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That response type is a JSON formatted string, it's a standard response type, not an issue. To read the value you need to parse the result from a JSON string to an array of objects, then access it.

Also note that you need to remove the `JSON.parse` reference within the `send()` call and define the `load` event handler *before* you send the request. Try this:

```js
function getaccountid() {
  var accID = new XMLHttpRequest();
  accID.addEventListener('load', function() {
    let responseObject = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    sessionStorage.setItem("accountId", responseObject[0]['_id']);
    console.log(responseObject[0]['_id']); // = 1
  }); 

  accID.open('GET', "http://127.0.0.1:8080/account/" + sessionStorage.getItem("username"), true);
  accID.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  accID.send();
}
```

Comment: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.
    at getaccountid

It returned this error on my browser's console log. I have tried rearranging the order of codes. Am I missing something? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The code you update works! It is now returning 1. However, when I store it in session, it is giving me [object XMLHttpRequest]. I have tried .respondType, .RepondText, .message.

Comment: I'm not sure how you've managed that. Just put the `responseObject[0]['_id']` value in the session, not the entire `accID` object

Comment: `sessionStorage.setItem("accountId", responseObject[0]['_id'])`
Like this? 
It is giving me a responseObject is not defined.

Comment: That means that `responseObject` is not in scope of wherever you've added that line. It has to go in the `load` handler function, as that's executed after the XMLHttpRequest completes and the value is available for use in the page. I updated the answer to show you exactly where